# Amazon web services - SQS - Lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

Currently I have a lambda function that is triggered by S3 PUT events, the lambda creates a SQS message with the name of the S3 bucket/Key. This lambda fills up the que with all the new S3 Keys being put in.

The S3 buckets contain zip files which my main goal is to unzip , process and store data with these files.

What is the best service to use to put all of my java code in to do this process as lambda itself is limited to memory size. I need something that reads the que to get the S3 bucket names then connects to them and does all the processing I want. I have all the actuall code done for processing but I am not sure if i should use AWS batch, Ec2, spark or whatever. I am unfamiliar with these services and it seems amazon offers a million services that essentially do that same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup autoscaling EC2 instances, which reads messages from SQS, unzip the files and write back to a bucket.

You can get an indepth understanding by reading [this](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/Amazon-SQS/1464) link.

Note: It would be preferred to have a different bucket for the unzipped files to improve throughput with S3.

Comment: I think my work flow may go something like this now. Lambda is triggered by incoming S3 event. Send the record(new s3 event location) to a mysql database. Then create a docker container that reads the database with all the new s3 buckets and connects to s3 to do unzipping an such on Amazon batch which uses ec2.

Comment: I would prefer s3 event trigger to put message to sqs and then process, since the reliability of message becomes a responsibility of aws. Also using docker or ec2 is an option and I feel its mainly based on the size of the files and amount of processing needed. Use the best EC2 class for unzipping for optimal performance.

Answer (score 0):

They've just added sqs as a source for lambdas (not sure when but I can certainly add SQS as a source in lambda now). Can't see any reference to this on the internet yet though (this is in Ireland region).